# Sidebar Link Not Working

Tags: jekyll, static-content

I'm using Hyde theme [(it's version 2.0)](https://github.com/poole/hyde#themes)

Having trouble with making sidebar's 'About' link to work.

It's hosted at [Github's Pages](http://arubyist.github.io/MapExplorer/). (my github repositiory)

Here's the default code that's in sidebar.html. How do I make the 'About' link work?

```
 <div class="sidebar">
 <div class="container sidebar-sticky">
    <div class="sidebar-about">
  <h1>{{ site.title }}</h1>
  <p class="lead">{{ site.description }}</p>
</div>

<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li class="sidebar-nav-item{% if page.title == "Home" %} active{% endif %}">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>

  {% comment %}
    The code below dynamically generates a sidebar nav of pages with
    `layout: page` in the front-matter. See readme for usage.
  {% endcomment %}

  {% assign pages_list = site.pages %}
  {% for node in pages_list %}
    {% if node.title != null %}
      {% if node.layout == "page" %}
        <li class="sidebar-nav-item{% if page.url == node.url %} active{% endif %}">
          <a href="{{ node.url }}">{{ node.title }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  <li class="sidebar-nav-item"><a href="/about.md">About</a></li>
  <li class="sidebar-nav-item"><a href="{{ site.github.repo }}/archive/v{{ site.version }}.zip">Download</a></li>
  <li class="sidebar-nav-item"><a href="{{ site.github.repo }}">GitHub project</a></li>
  <li class="sidebar-nav-item">Currently v{{ site.version }}</li>
</ul>

<p>&copy; {{ site.time | date: '%Y' }}. All rights reserved.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **{{ site.baseurl }}** missing in from your links.

```
  {% assign pages_list = site.pages %}
  {% for node in pages_list %}
    {% if node.title != null %}
      {% if node.layout == "page" %}
        <li class="sidebar-nav-item{% if page.url == node.url %} active{% endif %}">
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ node.url }}">{{ node.title }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  <li class="sidebar-nav-item"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/about/">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Markdown will be rendered to html, it should be:

`<li class="sidebar-nav-item"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/about/">About</a></li>`

I just forked your repo, see here:

http://www.madhur.co.in/MapExplorer/about/

Comment: hey, thanks for forking my repo and for letting me about `+markdown_ext: "markdown,mkdown,mkdn,mkd,md"` Appreciate it.